# ZonedDateTime Not Parsed Correctly If Sent As URL Request Parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a Controller which accepts a POJO (`MySearch`) representing optional request parameters.  Requests succeed when the `id` and/or `name` parameter(s) are included.

However, if I include the `dateTime` parameter like so:

```
GET /find?dateTime=2019-03-15T22:17:42Z&id=1432&name=Bob
```

I get an error:

```
Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.time.ZonedDateTime] 
for value '2019-03-15T22:17:42Z'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Parse attempt failed for value [2019-03-15T22:17:42Z]
```

I also tried annotating the `dateTime` field with `@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE_TIME)`, but that didn't help.

Serialization of `ZonedDateTime` fields in other tests successfully format the date/time similar to `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ` in the output.

It is only the *deserialization* of the `ZonedDateTime` field in the POJO that I'm having difficulty with.

### Controller

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/find")
    public MyResponse find(MySearch search) {
        // Do stuff ...
    }
}
```

### The POJO

```
public class MySearch {

    private Integer id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private ZonedDateTime dateTime;
}
```

### Configuration

I configured the `ObjectMapper` using these two beans:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder() {
    return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
            .modulesToInstall(new Jdk8Module(), new JavaTimeModule())
            .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS,
                    DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    return builder.build();
}
```

What am I missing, or doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It may not be your issue, but you ought to URL encode the parameter. As an aside your string seems to pass as an `Instant` better than a `ZonedDateTime`, so you may want to consider changing the type.

Comment: @ole-v-v  I tried URL-encoding the string, but received the same error.  So I changed `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant`, but again, received the parsing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to deserialize this object you need to register it as a new converter. In order to do so you can create a class similar to this one:

```
@Configuration
public class ZoneDateTimeWebMvcConfigurator implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToZoneDateTime());
    }

    static class StringToZoneDateTime implements Converter<String, ZonedDateTime> {
        @Override
        public ZonedDateTime convert(String value) {
            return ZonedDateTime.parse(value);
        }
    }
}
```